# Highchart: xAxis Label text not displayed when plotting 2 points

Tags: highcharts, label, formatter

I am using a Area/line chart and plotting for 2 points. Also using a xAxis Label formatter property for customizing the label to display as follows. But when using this the chart is not generated. And also I tried to remove the formatter property, the chart id generated but the xAxis label is displayed as 0.5 [At least we need to get label text from categories]. I have included 2 jsfiddle url where we tried two approaches. Please help and provide solution for displaying the xAxis label what we provided in the categories.

JsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jw2p5Lxa/17/ 
http://jsfiddle.net/p2EYM/116/

```
labels: {           
         formatter: function() {              
                    return this.value.substring(0, this.value.indexOf('_'));
            }
```

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: why `categories: ['Jan 12_Jan 12', '_Feb 12'],` is like that

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/jw2p5Lxa/4/  is that you want

Comment: Yes. But we don't need the Left and right space. The point should starts at the plot points and should end at end plot point. For that I used min and max.

Answer (score 0):

You've essentially told the chart, with your min and max values, to cut off the first and last label.

Get rid of this:

```
min: 0.5,
max: categories.length - 1.5,
```

And use this:

```
minPadding:0,
maxPadding:0,
```

Updated Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/p2EYM/118/

Output:

[image]

Comment: Can you please to use the jsfiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/jw2p5Lxa/17/, to check whether this works?

Comment: Tried in http://jsfiddle.net/jw2p5Lxa/18/ using minPadding and maxPadding, still I see the left and right spacing. Please verify

Comment: Yeah, Highstock and Highcharts seem to handle it differently. Have you considered using a `datetime` axis instead of categories? This might make it easier to resolve. Categories restrict how much you can manipulate the axis in ways that a `datetime` axis won't.

Answer (score 0):

You can save categories in an array and use xAxis.formater() to display specific label in your first example:

```
var categories = ['Jan 12_Jan 12', 'Feb 12_Feb 12'];

formatter: function() {
    return categories[this.value];
}
```

Also, do not use min and max properties. In the second example getting rid of min/max should be enough.

Examples:

http://jsfiddle.net/jw2p5Lxa/21/

http://jsfiddle.net/p2EYM/120/